# Filtering causes both lists to delete their Items - Android RecyclerView Filtering Java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-filterable, android-filter

So what i want to do is simply filter all of my entries according to a searchString. This works fine but for some reason everytime i filter both lists delete the items. i will only include the (i think) important parts of code here.

Adapter.java:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return myFilter;
    }

    private Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Stellplatz> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d("TEst","Size stellplaetzeall:"+ stellplaetzeall.size());

            Log.d("TEst","Size Stellplaeztze:"+ stellplaetze.size());

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(stellplaetzeall);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (Stellplatz item : stellplaetzeall) {
                    if (item.getAnbieter().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            stellplaetze.clear();
            stellplaetze.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

Fragment.java

```
@Override
     public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_itemlist, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
     }
```

I cant see why this would happen. Every example i found is basically the same as my code but for some reason it happens. i would really appreciate any answer that helps me understand this. also im not very good at android programming, first time doing this so an explanation why would be really helpful!

Comment: Where did you call `performFiltering`?

Comment: everytime i filter which happens on the "OnQueryChanged" - basically the getFilter returns the "myFilter"

Comment: Can you edit your question with more details about `OnQueryChanged`?

Comment: OnQueryTextChanged i meant. not onQueryChanged. But all it does is triggering the adapter.getFilter

Answer (score 0):

On publish Result you are clearing the List, i think that is wrong:

```
 @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        //stellplaetze.clear();
        stellplaetze.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I have an example of my code i think this will help:

First i create 2 list:

```
private ArrayList<CountryPhone> objects;
private ArrayList<CountryPhone> filteredData;

 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CountryPhone getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}
```

On Filter Results:

```
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<CountryPhone> filterlist = new ArrayList<>();

            String name, code;
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                CountryPhone item = objects.get(i);
                name = item.getName().toLowerCase();

                code = item.getCode();

                if (name.contains(filterString) || code.contains(filterString)){
                    filterlist.add(item);
                }
            }

            filterResults.values = filterlist;
            filterResults.count = filterlist.size();

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<CountryPhone>) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

};
```

Comment: true, but why would that clear "stellplaetzeall"? that it clears stellplaetze makes sense since it only needs to show the result data. which is stored in stellplaetze. and in stellplaetzeall should be everything so when the query is empty it shows all entries

Comment: I can´t understand well the answer, but if you delete the results, im going to edit my post and explain it better

Comment: What i mean is this: all data is initially stored in both lists. So both lists contain all Data-entries i need. Then when filtering, the filtered Dataentries are stored in the list called "Stellplaetze". At this point tho according to the log.d both lists only contain the filtered results. and i dont know why this happens at all. StellplaetzeAll is never edited after i fill it initially.

Comment: Did my example help?

Comment: i already tried this, but all it does is that one of my lists in getting bigger and bigger. it adds all the items to the end of list like intended but it shows me all items all times. the clear does not seem to be the issue here.